# How is the best way to use zend framework filters in forms?

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework, frameworks, filter

So, I have a problem when using filters in forms in Zend Framework.

When you set a filter on your form element, it filters the data provided to element, in all ways. So, if I call isValid() on the form, a 'Int' filter will convert the string "1" to an int 1. But if I set the element's value to a string "1", that value still will be converted to an int 1.

That behavior brings me a problem. For example, by the rules of the enterprise, all float value must be multiplied by 100 before save it to db (yeah, that sucks). So, i created a filter for that, and 10 becomes 1000. But when populate the form, 1000 becomes 100000.

I want a way to do that without work that in the model, only in the form. So, i thought to create a flag, to specify when the filter should be called.

Is there a better way to do that? I swear I did looked for that around, but I didn't find anything.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is in the database and what is in your model is part of the model-layer. In this case the mapper should take care of converting. You should not move this to the form, which is in fact more part of the view-layer, than anything else.

Comment: Might be, but that's not all true. Zend_Form is a facility, and does some boring and laborious work for us. I think that validators are part of the model's work, and filters, form generation, etc, are part of the view's work. Therefore, Zend_Form should have a way to specify the use of filters, giving us a more complete functionality and less work.

Comment: @DenisLins OK, Zend_Form is at all a curious thing ;) However, you didn't _verify_ the input with Zend_Form, do you? This compared to validation is the same relationship as in bringing the input in a sanitized form and bringing the input into the persistent form.

Comment: I agree with KingCrunch that the mapper should be doing this conversion, not the form. Presumably when you pull the values out of the DB you are dividing them by 100 - where do you have this logic if not in a mapper?

Answer (score 0):

Id guess the best way to do it is to set a flag and extend getvalue and setvalue.

setValue would always divide the number per 100 while getValue would always multiply it if the flag (which implies the filter) is present.

Comment: It is possibly the best solution, but when applied directly in the framework. Doing that now implies extending the Zend_Form_Element class, and rewriting all the form elements to extend that class, which I think it's give us too much work to do. Besides, it can become a problem in the future when some part of some element is changed.

Comment: For a framework wide solution this would be the only way. But you could just extend the element in question after all it isn't a general case and used by an specific situation. A framework is suposed to provide a general solution while the developers are expected to extend it for theirs specific needs. 

But i can see your point. Since the filters are in place there are times where you want the use input to be unaffected by em. And they should work both ways but this would require every filter to have a revert method. A nice feature indeed.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this kind of filtering in the form you do not need to mess with Zend_Form_Element_* at all. Just write a pair of [filters](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.filter.writing_filters.html). [Zend_Form](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.elements.html#zend.form.elements.filters) uses the available filters from Zend_Filter.
[Zend_filter](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.filter.writing_filters.html) has an extendable interface for building your own filters just the same as Zend_Validate.
Once you write your filters you can use them anywhere you need them. Zend_Form to filter input and in your model to filter the data back to original.

Good Luck.